# Getting Symfony3 dropdown field, built using EntityType, to default to previous value

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm struggling with finding the right solution to this problem.

I have a form with a dropdown which I want to generate dynamically via a call to a DB using the EntityType field. Everything works perfectly however I have been unable to get it to default to the previous value upon edit. All other fields in the form (all text) default to the previous value and if I build the field manually using ChoiceType it defaults as expected.

I have tried using the 'data' option to manually set it but it did not work. Short of building this as a ChoiceType and sending the data via the controller are there other things I should attempt?

Here is my form class TerminologyType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class TerminologyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        // Event listener added to prevent users from editing the unique
        // code after it has been created.
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $terminology = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            // check if the Terminology object is "new"
            // This should be considered a new "Terminology" and user must enter a code
            if (!$terminology || null === $terminology->getCode()) {
                $form->add('code');
            }

        });
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('version')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('status', EntityType::class, [
              'class' => 'AppBundle:CodeSet',
              'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.terminologyCode = :code')
                ->setParameter('code', 'entity_status')
                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
              'choice_label' => 'name',
              'choice_value' => 'code',
            ]);

}
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Terminology',
        ));
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Terminology;
use AppBundle\Form\TerminologyType;

/**
 * Terminology controller.
 *
 * @Route("/admin/terminology")
 */
class TerminologyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Terminology entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="terminology_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
....



/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Terminology entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{code}/edit", name="terminology_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Terminology $terminology)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($terminology);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\TerminologyType', $terminology);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        $em->persist($terminology);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('terminology_show', array('code' => $terminology->getCode()));
    }

    return $this->render('terminology/edit.html.twig', array(
        'terminology' => $terminology,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**Entity**

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Entity/Terminology.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @Gedmo\Loggable
  * @ORM\Table(name="ts_terminology")
  * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="dateDeleted", timeAware=false)
  * @UniqueEntity("code")
  *
  */

class Terminology extends TerminologyServices
{

  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=75)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeSet", mappedBy="terminologyCode")
     * @ORM\Id
   */
     protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=75, nullable=true)
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CodeSet")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName="code")
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
   */
     protected $status;
```

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Comment: Added now.  Wasn't sure it was relevant or not. I'm wondering if it has to do with my column mapping.  I'm still struggling to understand the doctrine relationship mapping.

Comment: Are you new to Symfony? What are you expecting your Controller to do? It looks like you create a $deleteForm in the `editAction()` function, but I don't see on Symfony's site any reference to "createDeleteForm". You also don't show your TWIG file "terminology/edit.html.twig", maybe you do something in there?

Comment: Yes new to symfony after a long hiatus (symfony 1.4) I didn't include all parts of the controller because I didn't think it was relevant to the original question (I could be wrong). The starting code was created using the symfony CRUD generator (which created the delete form code).

Comment: In terms of the controller action (editAction), basically it loads the existing values from the database and populates a form.  Upon submission it validates and persists and redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track down the problem.  In the entity definition for status I had defined the column type, length, etc in the annotations.
  @ORM\Column(type="string", length=75, nullable=true)

By removing this it began defaulting to the last entered value (however this subsequently broke other things). I believe this has to do with EntityType expecting an object but the entity type being defined as a string and only providing that (which explains why ChoiceType option worked).